# Virtuoso Or PHP Web Framework For URL Routing

Tags: php, sparql, rdf, slim, virtuoso

I'm running Virtuoso Open Source 7.  The goal is a simple URL structure ex `www.example.com/diabetes`.  The virtual directory is setup to load `index.vsp`, which parses VSP & HTML, but not PHP (neither inside or outside the `<?vsp ?>` tags).  Having Slim web framework experience, I'm used to creating routes ex

```
@/
call method index

@/{page}
call method page(page)
```

Because VSP isn't parsing PHP & vice versa, it seems I must choose PHP/Slim to make URL routing work.  Is this so, or can I somehow code VSP file/stay in Virtuoso?

Regards

Comment: You could configure Apache to parse vsp as php file.

Comment: Hi Mika.  Thanks for the comment.  To clarify, I'd like to parse VSP & PHP.  AFAIK Apache can't parse VSP code, only Virtuoso can

Comment: Virtuoso-specific questions are often answered faster and more accurately via the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), public [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or confidential [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Answer (score 0):

[Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) (from [my employer](http://www.openlinksw.com/)) can be set up to handle both its [native VSP](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/vsp1.html) and [add-on PHP](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/servphpext.html) in-process, with either/both [URL Rewriting](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtuosoUrlRewriting) or [Virtual Directories](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/dataspace/owiki/wiki/VirtuosoWikiWeb/CreateAVirtualDirectoryMapping).